# PHP-FPM: Does error_reporting() override php_admin_value[error_reporting]?

Tags: php

I use PHP 7.4.12 with php-fpm. According to the documentation for php-fpm worker conf:

```
;   php_admin_value/php_admin_flag - these directives won't be overwritten by
;                                     PHP call 'ini_set'
```

I have set

```
php_admin_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 32767
```

And when I run:

```
<?php

echo "ERROR REPORTING: ".ini_get('error_reporting')."\n";
echo "DISPLAY ERRORS: ".ini_get('display_errors')."\n";
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
echo "ERROR REPORTING: ".ini_get('error_reporting')."\n";
echo "DISPLAY ERRORS: ".ini_get('display_errors')."\n";
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
echo "ERROR REPORTING: ".ini_get('error_reporting')."\n";
echo "DISPLAY ERRORS: ".ini_get('display_errors')."\n";
error_reporting(0);
echo "ERROR REPORTING: ".ini_get('error_reporting')."\n";
echo "DISPLAY ERRORS: ".ini_get('display_errors')."\n";
```

The output is

```
ERROR REPORTING: 32767
DISPLAY ERRORS: 0
ERROR REPORTING: 32767
DISPLAY ERRORS: 0
ERROR REPORTING: 32767
DISPLAY ERRORS: 0
ERROR REPORTING: 0
DISPLAY ERRORS: 0
```

So is the official documentation wrong, as it says that (in [Example #1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)):

```
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Or is this a bug specific to PHP 7.4.12?

Comment: The docs only mention `ini_set()` and do not explicitly state that the settings will be unaffected by `error_reporting()` as well. So this is certainly not a bug. But the docs are a little vague in that you have to take the wording literally. I can understand your confusion as `error_reporting()` and `ini_set()` are often mentioned in the same breath.

Comment: the docs do say its the same in code example

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Added link to the question - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php Example #1